# How to update command line output?

Tags: c, linux, command-line

In Linux, While `stdout` to command line, I want to update specific area, such as the `apt-get` output:

```
54% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]        211 kB/s 3s
```

the *percentage*, *kB/s* and *second* will update each second.

If we use `printf` then we will get multiple lines output them. I have tried following `printf`:

```
printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
```

But it cleans all the output.

My question is how to update specific area and keep others stable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the carriage return. It will move the cursor back to the start of the line, from which you can overwrite what was in the line before. For example:

```
printf("Hello, world!\rX");
```

Will be visible as:

```
Xello, world!
```

Make sure you flush `stdout` often if you want it to be visible:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: You may want to add `\027[k` after `\r` to clear the line. This assumes ANSI terminal escape sequences, which most terminals support.

Answer (score 3):

In addition (of the useful `\r` & `fflush` [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15714139/841108) above), if you want a full screen console output, consider using [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). If you want an editable input line, the [GNU readline](http://www.gnu.org/software/readline) library is useful too!