# Is there any standard to create console applications?

Tags: c++, linux, command-line-interface

I want to create console applications for linux and I was wondering if there is any standard for the output of applications?

Should I follow some guidelines, or can I do whatever I want?

If there is a standard, does anyone know if there is a library I can use to output properly?  I;m programming in C++.

Comment: Read from `std::cin`, write to `std::cout`, and you're done?

Comment: `ncurses` is a fantastic library.

Comment: Isn't "doing whatever you want" kind of the point of programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to follow most of the [GNU coding standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/). In particular, from a naive user's point of view, I really like the `--help` and `--version` options (which are sadly not mandated by Posix). You may want to use, for parsing of program arguments, the [argp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html) functions provided by GNU Libc.

You may want to use `ncurses` for full-screen console input & output, or GNU `readline` to read an editable line of input. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8286514/841108) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15715874/841108) answers.

I also suggest you to make your console applications [free software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) (e.g. [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) licensed) and publish them on some versioned repository like [github](http://github.com) or [gitorious](http://gitorious.org) etc etc...

Answer (score 1):

Almost all (Linux) command line utilities follow the [posix guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html), although this is mostly about command line parameters and not so much output.